# Poisson question in word problem

Tags: probability

I have a problem: the number of people entering a casino every hour is a poisson distribution with an average of 30 per hour. What is the probability no one enters between 12 and 12:05?

I do not understand how the poisson process can be applied here. Each hour has finite time, but the poisson requires infinite time to sum to 1.

Comment: "The Poisson requires infinite time to sum to 1": could you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: "*the poisson requires infinite time to sum to 1*"... you seem to be confused as to what the poisson distribution is describing.  Given a specific duration of time, it gives the probability of zero, one, two, three, four, ... people arriving.  If you are going to be summing anything to infinity, it is the *number of people arriving*, not the length of time.  Although incredibly unlikely, under the poisson model, you could potentially have a thousand or a million or more people arriving at the casino during the same hour.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was what I was confused about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Poisson process with average of 30 people per 60 minutes or 2.5 people per five minute interval, or:

$P[k] = {e^{-2.5} 2.5^k \over k!}$.

To find the probability of $k=0$, just plug in to get $P[0] = 1/e^{2.5} = 0.082085$.
[image]